# What does "I didn't even go to how huge something is" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrases

I have come across in the second episode of the eighth season of *Friends*. Here is the context:

> Rachel: Phoebe the father is not here okay? I haven’t told him yet and
> I don’t think I can tell him at all now!
>
> Phoebe: Why not?
>
> Rachel: I don’t know, let me think. I was walking down the street
> thinking, ‘I’m gonna tell the father today’ and then bam!
>
> Phoebe: Bus?
>
> Rachel: No, you! Phoebe you freaked me out. You kept saying how huge
> this all is!
>
> Phoebe: Well-well but it is huge.
>
> Rachel: I know, but I was just thinking about how huge this is for me.
> **I didn’t even go to how huge this was** going to be for the father.

Comment: Rachel thought about how huge it was for her, but didn't even proceed to ('go to'), in her thoughts, (even start to think about) how huge it was going to be for the father.

Comment: This is, BTW, a very unusual phrasing, perhaps indicating how upset she is by how disordered her speech is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn’t even go to how huge this was going to be for the father = I didn’t even consider how huge this was going to be for the father.